# CUDA and thread blocks overhead

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I've implemented a simple kernel that calculate matrix multiplication. This is the code:

```
__global__ void MatMultKernel(Mat A, Mat B, Mat C){

int i;
double val=0.0;
int ix=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;  
int iy=blockDim.y*blockIdx.y+threadIdx.y;
if(ix<A.nrows && iy<B.nrows){
    for(i=0;i<A.nrows;i++)
        val+=A.value[iy*A.nrows+i]*B.value[i*B.nrows+ix];
    C.value[iy*C.nrows+ix]=val;
 }
}
```

I measured the running time of this kernel by varying threads and blocks configurations.

I've seen execution times are always worse if threads are allocated in column blocks (for example dim3 (1,256,1)) What is the reason?

Comment: What is the size of the input arrays?

Comment: 1024x1024 and 2048x2048

Comment: For example: threadsxblocks=(1,256,1) elapsed time = 3.106 s
 threadsxblocks=(16,16,1) elapsed time = 0.325 s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me point out that your code works only for square matrices, generally you should use `A.ncols` instead of `A.nrows` in all three places in your code.

The performance difference is due to memory access. You have all three matrices stored in row-major format and the code does the following: each thread accesses the `iy`-th row of `A` and `ix`-th column of `B` and computes their dot product. Note that all threads in a warp always execute the same instruction at the same time, so in the serial loop in your code `i` is always the same for all threads in a warp. In your code, the block shape matters, because:

- If the block size is `(256, 1, 1)`, then each thread in a block has the same `iy`, but different `ix`. Let's take a look at the access pattern to `B`: all threads in the same warp always access the same row of `B`, because in `B.value[i*B.nrows+ix]` the `i` is the same and `ix` differs, so the loads can be [coalesced](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).
- If the block size is `(1, 256, 1)`, then the situation is transposed, so you'd probably expect the loads from `A` to be coalesced. But that is not the case, because `iy` determines the row and the values accessed by two neighboring threads are offset by `A.ncols`.

The access pattern to `C` is the same as for `B`, but much less important. With a 2D block the situation is somewhere between the two 1D cases.

If you want to optimize your code further, you can use the shared memory as shown in the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory).